# Discord py │ Bot Give Role

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot give role after a command is being called but I'm not sure what is the right command. I searched online but every single one I tried gave an error. Anyone know the correct form of the command?

The code:

```
#iports the discord folder and commands for our bot
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext import tasks



#sets the command prefix
Client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";")

#print Nuggie is ready in the console when the bot is activeted
@Client.event
async def on_ready():
    await Client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game("With Your Mom"))
    print("Nuggie is ready")


@Client.command()
async def setup_verification(ctx, arg):
    channel_id = 768983636296204318
    await clear(ctx)
    Text = "send  ;verify  to this message to get verified and get access to the server!"
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title = "Verify your identity", description = Text, color = 0xC311EF)
    embedVar.add_field(name = "\u200B", value = "\u200B")
    embedVar.add_field(name = "This proccess in crucial for the server.", value = "Without this, the server is exposed to raids." , inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    #await ctx.send(Text)

@Client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    channel = 768983636296204318
    if discord.TextChannel.id == channel:
        clear()
        await ctx.send("This message is not available in this channel! Pls only use command where it's supposed to be!")
    else:
        author = ctx.message.author.name
        #Role = discord.utils.get(author.server.roles, name="Member")
        await Message.add_roles(author, "Member")
        #roleRemove = get(user.server.roles, name='member')
        await Client.remove_role(author, "Unverified")
        await ctx.send(f"{author} you are verified!")
        await asyncio.sleepdelay(s = 60)
        clear(ctx, 2)

Client.run('My_Token')
```

and the error I get when I run verify is:

```
Ignoring exception in command verify:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\roy\Desktop\Folders\Atom\Discord Bot\Nuggie.py", line 40, in verify
    await Message.add_roles(author, "Member")
NameError: name 'Message' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'Message' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `Member` object and you can call `add_roles()` on it. `ctx.author` is your Member object, now you need to get your Role object. There is different ways to get the Role object. You can get it by ID using [`Guild.get_role(role_id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) or you can get it by name using [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

```
memberRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Member')
```

Now since you have your Member object and your Role object you can simply call [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) on your Member object.

```
await ctx.author.add_roles(memberRole)
```

Same thing to remove the Unverified role, except you call [`Member.remove_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles)

Comment: It kind of worked, now it's not giving an error but not giving the role either...